# failing to dump the input file reversed

Tags: c, c89

I want to reverse the contents of the input file and display the reversed contents, but I am not getting it; i think I have made a logic error.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char* c = malloc(10);
    char* c1 = malloc(10);
    char ch, arg1[100], arg2[100];
    int i, count = 0;
    FILE *fp, *fq;
    printf("Name of the file:");
    scanf("%s", arg1);
    fp = fopen(arg1, "w+");
    if (!fp) {
        perror("Failed to open file");
        return errno;
    }

    printf("\t\t\t%s\n\n", arg1);
    printf("\t\tInput the text into the file\n");
    printf("\t\tPress Ctrl+d to the stop\n");
    while ((*c=getchar()) != EOF) {
        fwrite(c, 1, sizeof(c), fp);
        count++;
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen(arg1, "w+");
    printf("Name of the output file:");
    scanf("%s", arg2);
    printf("Reversing the contents of the file.......\n");
    fq = fopen(arg2, "w+");
    printf("\t\t%s\n\n", arg2);
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        fseek(fp, -(i + 1), SEEK_END)
        fwrite(c1, 1, sizeof(c1), fq);
    }
    printf("Done....Opening the file\n");
    rewind(fq);
    for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        ch = getc(fp);
        putc(ch, stdout);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fq);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting? What have you tried to do to fix the problem? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: If the content of the file is small, you might want to load everything into memory and then reverse it there. That `fseek(...)` and then `rewind()` look awfully inefficient to me.

Comment: i have the compiled the program on my linux and i unable to get output of the reversed contents

Comment: i agree with u abeln but i did it wantedly just to solve the question

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html

Comment: hint: sizeof(c) == sizeof(char *) != 1.  You also never put anything into c1 before you write it to your output file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example program which loads the file into memory and then prints the content of the memory backwards to stdout.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* get the size of the file. No error checking here! */
long get_filesize(FILE *fp)
{
    long fsize;

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    return fsize;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argv[1] == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    FILE *input;
    unsigned char *data;
    long filesize;
    int i;

    /* open target file */
    input = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if(input == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    /* retrieve size of the file */
    filesize = get_filesize(input); 
    if(filesize < 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    /* allocate space for the file */
    data = malloc(filesize * sizeof(unsigned char));
    if(data == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    /* read the file into buffer and close the file handle */
    fread(data, filesize, sizeof(unsigned char), input);
    fclose(input);

    /* print the file content from end to beginning */
    for(i = --filesize; i >= 0; --i)
        putchar(data[i]);

    /* free the data buffer memory */
    free(data);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Input text:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
specimen book.
```

Output text:

```
.koob nemiceps epyt a ekam ot ti delbmarcs dna epyt fo yellag a koot retnirp
nwonknu na nehw ,s0051 eht ecnis reve txet ymmud dradnats s'yrtsudni eht neeb
sah muspI meroL .yrtsudni gnittesepyt dna gnitnirp eht fo txet ymmud ylpmis si
muspI meroL
```

Comment: @Athabaska, your program accesses memory outside the buffer allocated for `data` - you need a `- 1` in there somewhere.  There's also no reason to multiply by `sizeof(unsigned char)` in the `malloc` call - it's always going to be `1`.

Comment: Already fixed. This stackoverflow system is nasty. Somebody always comments at the same time when I am fixing errors. But no offense taken. Glad somebody catches these nasty C errors. As for the `sizeof(unsigned char)`, usually I add it just for portability. I think it is a good practice.

Comment: @Athabaska - no sweat, just trying to help out!

Comment: how can we use data[i] as data is a pointer to a single char ,but the compiler doesn't show error

Comment: @ar3 in C arrays are actually pointers to the first element of the array. So after we allocate space for the data pointer, it becomes "array" and we can access it like normal array.

Comment: @Athabaska Dick : No standard-compliant compiler in existence can have `sizeof(unsigned char)` be anything other than `1`.

Comment: I am tired of everybody complaining about that. I personally add that `for clarity` like many many other programmers too. There are endless flamewars about this subject on stackoverflow.